# Add Carriage Return when writing an XML file (powershell)

Tags: xml, powershell, xmlwriter

Trying to format my xml file and I can't find out how to setup powershell to do this. Everything references C++ or C# :(

This is how I want it to look:

```
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

But this is how it looks:

```
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

Yuk right? I have tried different ways in powershell, I cannot get it to add the space. Below is what looked to be the most promising, but it has no effect.

```
$settings = New-Object system.Xml.XmlWriterSettings 
$settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = $false 
$settings.NewLineOnAttributes = $true

$XmlWriter = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($path,$null)

$xmlWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
$xmlWriter.Indentation = 1
$XmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"
```

Thanks for anybody who has an Idea !!

Comment: I like it to look pretty, i realize it has no impact at all on the functionality.

Comment: The only way probably is to open that file as plain text, build some regex to identify your attributes, maintain control over the indentation and insert those tabs; too much pain for no result, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this isn't possible in powershell (without actually [loading C# code](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx))

The following code returns an error:

```
$settings = New-Object system.Xml.XmlWriterSettings;
$settings.Indent = $true;
$settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = $true;
$settings.NewLineOnAttributes = $true;

$path = 'c:\test\meh.xml'

Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Xml'

$writerClass = New-Object XML.XmlTextWriter $path, ([Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
$writer = New-Object ([System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($writerClass,$settings))

New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingWriter]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

[XmlCharCheckingWriter is an internal class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/11/01/487940.aspx) which may be the cause of the problem?. I'm not sure how you would make this work with powershell.